# How to use the Google calendar API's functions

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google calendar API and I can't properly call the built-in functions. For reference:

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');

while(true) {
    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo $event->getSummary();
    }
    $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This code return a fatal error:

> Call to a member function `getItems()` on a non-object

I don't understand how to use an object which is not instantiated by a `New()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add this line into your code

```
$client->setUseObjects(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it just before the following line

```
$service = new apiCalendarService($client);
```

Since

```
$service->events->listEvents('primary');
```

returns an array but you need an object here